# Does Forward All forward the thread to the emails IN the converation as well?

Tags: gmail, email-forwarding

I recently used forward all in Gmail to send my probation officer a thread that has the contact of a person I can't make contact with. Does forward all forward the thread to the emails IN the conversation as well? I really hope not. I sent one person the thread believing only that person would receive it. In the sent folder it's showing the contacts (email addresses) in the thread were emailed to. Or that's how it appears. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

- **Reply** - will send a message only to the person from which you received the last email
- **Reply to all** - will send a message to all people which received the last email
- **Forward** - will prompt you to enter an email address
  [image]
- to be sure:
- click on **Sent** emails
- find that email you sent and open it
- click on the reversed triangle to **Show details**
- there you can see to whom you sent it

[image]

[image]